# How do I use the JSON data from my stream?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I set up a stream to listen to a particular node in Firebase Realtime Database. I now need to convert this into my `Message` model so that I can put it in my `ListView`'s `itemBuilder`, but before I could get to that point I'm getting an error when trying to simply print out `msg`. I'm new to Dart/Flutter, so I'm not quite sure yet as to how to use models.

> Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

```
//...
final _database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
late StreamSubscription _receivedChatsStream;
var data;
var dataList = [];
//...

void _activateListeners() { //Leading with '_' = private
    final groupIDPath = widget.groupIDPath;

    _receivedChatsStream = _database.child(groupIDPath).onValue.listen((event) {
         
      setState(() {
        data = new Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value);

        try {
          if (data != null) {
            data.forEach((k, v) => dataList.add(v));
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print('Received Chats ERROR: ' + e.toString());
        }

        var msg = Message.fromJson(dataList[0]).uid; //Error is pointing here
        if (msg.isNotEmpty) {
          print('msg is NOT empty');
        } else {
          print('msg is empty!');
        }

      });
    });
  }
```

**Message class:**

```
class Message { 
  final String uid;
  final String txt;
  final DateTime timestamp;

  Message({
    required this.uid,
    required this.txt,
    required this.timestamp
  });

  Message.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json): //Transform JSON into Message
        uid = json['uid'] as String,
        txt = json['txt'] as String,
        timestamp = DateTime.parse(json['timestamp'] as String);

  Map<dynamic, dynamic> toJson() => <dynamic, dynamic>{ //Transforms Message into JSON
    'uid': uid,
    'text': txt,
    'timestamp': timestamp.toString(),

  };

}
```

Comment: Is there any possibility that `uid` or `txt` or `timestamp` can be null ?

Comment: @madhan only if there are no records yet in that node, i.e. if the group has just been created. Otherwise, anytime the user writes a record, the uid, txt, and timestamp fields will all have a value.

Comment: 1. Make the variable nullable, `String uid` to `String? uid`

2. Or Use null aware `??` operator, `uid: json['uid'] as String` to `uid: json['uid'] ?? ""` //assign an empty string if the value is null.

Try to apply this for all the variables. This might help.